# json output has chinese characters, html shows question mark

Tags: php, html, json, nginx, utf-8

I have output in JSON and this contains the correct Chinese characters.

Verified this with postman, this shows the Chinese characters in the JSON output.

The JSON is sent with following PHP header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

However the HTML code is displaying question marks instead.
I have added the UTF8 meta tag in my header:

```
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Also in my NGINX configuration server part I added:

```
 charset utf-8;
```

In my php.ini I also set the default charset to UTF-8.

But the HTML keeps displaying question marks.

JSON generation code:

```
 $resultArray["result"] = "success";
 $resultCounter = 0;

 // in while loop add results from database
 $resultArray["userlist"][$resultCounter] = $userInfo;
 $resultCounter++;   

 //encode
 $result = json_encode($resultArray,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

JSON entry example

```
 {
        "browser": "Handheld Browser",
        "id": "23678",
        "mac": "48:4B:AA:40:0F:C1",
        "name": "\u76e7\u6b23\u9713",
        "os": "iPhone",
        "timestamp": "1488178109",
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea what I could be missing?

Comment: Paste your part of `json_encode` please. Anyway, do you try `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` yet?

Comment: I tried, see example code above but no result. I set the code up on my testserver which is apache, there the characters are fine. The live server is running nginx but there still shows question marks instead.

Comment: Do you resolve your question yet? If not, please paste your Chinese character here so I can test.

Comment: No I did not resolve yet, I added example JSON entry

Comment: I can see your unicode is `"name": "\u76e7\u6b23\u9713"` the original utf8 is `盧欣霓`, have you try this `json_encode("盧欣霓",JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`?

Comment: yes, the code is as above, I think it might have to do something with my nginx configuration as it seems to be working on apache.